# Error: React-Table: Could not find a column with id:

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to make my columns searchable, but I keep getting an error that says there are no columns with the id '-whatever I search for- '. I've search extensively, and I can't seem to find an explanation. I'm guessing the problem is in the data I'm passing.

Here's the code so far:

```
const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      Filter: ColumnTableFilter
    }),
    []
  )

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    setGlobalFilter,
  } = useTable(
    { 
      columns, 
      data,
      defaultColumn,
     },
    useFilters,
    useGlobalFilter
  );

  return (
    <div className="qtable-container" {...props}>
      {tableFilterable ?
        <div className='global-search-bar-container'>
          <GlobalTableFilter
            className='search-bar'
            preGlobalFilteredRows={preGlobalFilteredRows}
            globalFilter={state.globalFilter}
            setGlobalFilter={setGlobalFilter}
          />
        </div>
        : null
      }
      <table {...getTableProps()} className={generateClassName()}>
        <thead className='table-header'>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                {column.render('Header')}
                <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}</div>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()} >
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()} className='cell'>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>;
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    );
}
```

And the column filter:

```
  const count = column.preFilteredRows.length

  return (
    <TextInput
      value={column.filterValue || ''}
      onChange={e => {
        setFilter(e.target.value || undefined) // Set undefined to remove the filter entirely
      }}
      placeholder={`Search ${count} records...`}
    />
  )
}
```

and the data:

```
const data = React.useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                transformationCount: '21 Transforms',
                batchName: 'Avera_name',
                id: 1
            },
            {
                transformationCount: '14 Transforms',
                batchName: 'Jenn_name',
                id: 2
            },
            {
                transformationCount: '12 Transforms',
                batchName: 'Jude_name',
                id: 3
            }
        ],
        []
    );

    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                Header: 'Name',
                accessor: 'batchName', // accessor is the "key" in the data
            },
            {
                Header: 'Transformations',
                accessor: 'transformationCount'
            }
        ],
        []
  );
```

Comment: Having the same exact issue. Any luck?

Comment: I can't see your column filter method signature, but it looks like you're calling the setFilter method on the TableInstance instead of on the ColumnInstance. The setFilter method on TableInstance has a different signature that expects a columnId as the first parameter, which is why you're receiving that error message (your first parameter is the filter value). You should either call column.setFilter or else be sure you are deconstructing setFilter from the ColumnInstance instead of the TableInstance.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your column filter function. The 'column' object is undefined.

I had the same exact issue and the same exact code as yours. Here's the solution:

```js
function DefaultColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue, preFilteredRows, setFilter },
}) {
  const count = preFilteredRows.length; //Notice here I don't use column.preFilteredRows

  return (
    <CustomInput
      formControlProps={{
        fullWidth: true,
      }}
      inputProps={{
        value: filterValue || "", //Notice here as well I don't use column.filterValue
        onChange: (e: any) => {         
          setFilter(e.target.value || undefined); 
        },
        placeholder: `Buscar ${count} registros...`,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Soo, by removing the usage of the parameter 'column' inside the function, the code should be able to work now